# Is a std::list empty when it is first constructed - even if it is a member of a class?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have defined a class that contains a `std::list` as a member. When I create an object of that class, I expected the std::list to be empty. However, I queried the iterators returned by `begin()` and `end()` and found that they were not equal.

How can I ensure that my std::list member is empty on initial construction of the object?

Here is the code for my class:

```
typedef int ShapeHandle;
typedef void o_gadget;

class Gadget
{
public:
    Gadget( int c_id, int g_id, void * desc, size_t numbytes ):
        class_id(c_id), gadget_id(g_id)
        {
            memory = malloc( numbytes );
            father = 0;
            rightbro = 0;
            leftbro = 0;
            firstchild = 0;
            lastchild = 0;
            active = false;
            update = false;
        }
    void * memory;
    std::list<ShapeHandle> myshapes;
    std::list<o_gadget *> children;

    int class_id;
    int gadget_id;
    o_gadget * father;
    o_gadget * rightbro;
    o_gadget * leftbro;
    o_gadget * firstchild;
    o_gadget * lastchild;
    bool active;
    bool update;
};
```

I compared the iterators like this:

```
    ... 
    // search the tree stopping when we find the ID
Gadget * info = gadgets[from];
std::list<o_gadget *>::iterator iter = info->children.begin();
while( target == 0 && iter != info->children.end()  )
{
    FindGadget(ID, *iter, target);
    iter++;
}
    ...
```

I didn't expect that on inspecting a new `Gadget`, that `while` loop would be entered. I know that `target == 0` is true, so I figured that `iter != info->children.end()` was also true. However, I am not inspecting these values in a debugger.

### EDIT

I'm so sorry everyone. This is clearly wrong. I've done it again. I've posted a bug that isn't actually there. I can't reproduce it now. Can you all vote to close it - or can I close this thing myself?

Comment: Yes, it should be empty. Show us some code. You could also call `empty()` for additional verification.

Comment: How did you compare the iterators? If you did `mylist.begin() == mylist.end()` then that should be true. If you did `*mylist.begin() == *mylist.end()` then it need not necessarily be true. In theory because you did something undefined, in practice because `begin` and `end` don't have to return values with identical representations, just iterator values that compare equal.

Comment: Regarding the edit: show the code that calls `begin` and `end` and makes the comparison.

Comment: is "from" a valid index?

Comment: Regarding the second edit: nope, still nothing obviously wrong. I'm afraid you'll have to show a complete program which exhibits the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @BeeBand: You haven't posted code showing how you're doing the `list::begin()` and `list::end()` comparison; that code is likely more pertinent to solving your problem than your class declaration. Also, why are you using `malloc()` in C++?

Comment: @Praetorian, I am assembling some code that I can post. Re. the `malloc()` its because I want to allocate some raw memory just of a specific size. I pass it back to the user to fill, so I can't use `new` as I don't want to fill that memory with an object. What should I do instead?

Comment: @BeeBand: Assuming that you aren't going to change the interface, you could use a `vector<char>`, and pass the user a pointer to its first element. Even if you have to allocate raw memory, you can do that in C++ with `new char[numbytes]` or `::operator new(numbytes)` rather than `malloc`, although there isn't much to choose between them. I doubt that using `malloc` has anything to do with the question, though...

Comment: @BeeBand: Use `operator new` to create an empty `char*` buffer (or other byte buffer), then use "placement new" (use Google) to allocate an object in that space later.

Comment: @Steve, no it's probably nothign to do with question ( see my last edit ). However this is very interesting - why is vector<char> better than malloc?

Comment: @BeeBand: vector is better because you don't have to explicitly free anything in the destructor of `Gadget` to avoid memory leaks, and because the default copy assignment operator and copy constructor of `Gadget` will copy the data, rather than sharing it between objects. Sharing might have surprising results if the buffer is supposed to "belong" to a single Gadget, and would result in a double-free if you've put a call to `free` in the destructor to avoid memory leaks. Look up "RAII".

Answer (score 5):

The objects of std::list are created empty by default and therefore begin() should be equal to end().

I don't see anything wrong in your Gadget class and doing a simple check shows that the 'children' member variable is actually created empty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Gadget
{
// ...
};

int main()
{
    Gadget g(0, 0, 0, 0);
    std::cout << (g.children.begin() == g.children.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

It prints 1 because (begin() == end()) evaluates to true.

Were do you construct your 'gadgets' array?

Answer (score 3):

How are you determining that `begin()` and `end()` are returning different iterators? If you're inspecting their values in a debugger, that won't tell you much unless you know how `operator==` works on the iterators.

The `empty()` method can tell you directly if the list is empty or not.

**Edit:** The problem is almost certainly in the line `Gadget * info = gadgets[from];` which is returning a pointer to either a Gadget containing some stuff that you didn't show us, or more likely is an invalid pointer altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Does list::empty() return TRUE for your freshly constructed list?

Comment: Lol an **answer**  consisting of a single question... symbolic :)

Comment: No, it probably returns `true` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Newly constructed list (no constructor parameters) will be empty.

`begin()` and `end()` will not look identical in the debugger since they are both newly-constructed iterators on every call.

What do you mean by they are not equal?  `begin() == end()` returns `false`, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a program that (for me) correctly prints "1", indicating that the iterators are equal. If you gradually change your program towards this program, the step at which it changes behavior might tell you what was wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef int ShapeHandle;
typedef void o_gadget;

class Gadget
{
public:
    Gadget( int c_id, int g_id, void * desc, size_t numbytes ):
        class_id(c_id), gadget_id(g_id)
        {
            memory = std::malloc( numbytes );
            father = 0;
            rightbro = 0;
            leftbro = 0;
            firstchild = 0;
            lastchild = 0;
            active = false;
            update = false;
        }
    void * memory;
    std::list<ShapeHandle> myshapes;
    std::list<o_gadget *> children;

    int class_id;
    int gadget_id;
    o_gadget * father;
    o_gadget * rightbro;
    o_gadget * leftbro;
    o_gadget * firstchild;
    o_gadget * lastchild;
    bool active;
    bool update;
};

int main() {
    Gadget g(1,2,0,12);
    std::cout << (g.children.begin() == g.children.end()) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all of the constructors of the parent class explicitly initialize the list member, either in their initializer-list or within their function bodies.